# How to render texture into box2d objects from Tile Map? Libgdx

Tags: textures, rendering, camera, box2d

I have a problem, when i try to render textures. I read positions of gameObjects, for example coin and create box2d objects circle shape. I have wrote game logic and began make a graphic. But for some reason, textures drawing not in box2d objects, but they shifted to the right and up as mini-map in games.

### Code

```
  batcher.begin();

  sprite = new Sprite(AssetsLoader.coin);

  sprite.setPosition((body.getPosition().x - sprite.getWidth()/2), ((body.getPosition().y - sprite.getHeight()/2)));

  sprite.draw(batcher);
  batcher.end();
```

### This is what happened

[image]

As you can see above, sprite position like body position. And something else: when i move my mainHero all rendered coins moving with him. On the screen they save their position, but in world they are moving. So how i can render coin texture exactly into box2d body.

May be something wrang with camera?

```
cam = new OrthographicCamera();

cam.setToOrtho(false, 400, 600);
```

---

or with Batcher?

```
batcher = new SpriteBatch();

batcher.setProjectionMatrix(world.getCamera().combined);
```

---

I will not give all my code, because it is big and no one will try to understand it.I need an idea or just an advice or a hint. Sorry for my English, hello everyone from Belarus :) Where do I look and what a start? Thank you.

Comment: Are the objects in the same space? It seems like you're not compensating for the camera movement?

Comment: Yeah, the objects in the same space, yes, may be you are right, i am not compensating for the camera movement, But even when I have not done a single step, coins already displayed not on their positions and relatively as if some mythical camera's coordinate.@Sidar

Comment: Are you scaling your coins and if so does getWidth() scale ?

Comment: Now i understood. When i make my gamecamera equals to the gameworld dimensions and set its position in  cam.position.set(cam.viewportHeight/2, cam.viewportWidth/2, 0); all coins on their positions. @Sidar